# Structuremap resolve for a top level request insane same nested container

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap

All,

I need to configure StructueMap to resolve a new instance of a class per top level request inside a nested container.

Let me try and explain, all of the below code is a simplified example but should show what I'm trying to achieve.

The object that will be shared `IDependency`

The Service/Repository setup:

```
public class Service1
{   
    public Service1(Repository1 repository, IDependency dependency) { }
}

public class Service2
{
    public Service2(Repository2 repository, IDependency dependency) { }
}


public class Repository1
{   
    public Repository1(IDependency dependency) { }
}

public class Repository2
{
    public Repository2(IDependency dependency) { }
}
```

As you can see the dependencies are as so

`Service1` requires `Repository1` and `IDependency`, then Repository1 requires `IDependency`

`Service2` requires `Repository2` and `IDependency`, then Repository2 requires `IDependency`

For `Service1` and `Repository1` I want them to shared the same instance of `IDependancy`

Then for `Service2` and `Repository2` I want them to shared the same instance of `IDependancy`

but i don't want `Service1` and `Service2` to share the same instance of `IDependancy`

I'm resolving `Service1` and `Service2` like so

```
using (IContainer container = rootContainer.GetNestedContainer())
{    
    Service1 service1 = container.GetInstance<Service1>();
    Service2 service2 = container.GetInstance<Service2>();
}
```

Is it possible to get the service and repository to share the same instance of `IDependancy` but not share between different services, all within the same nested container, is it possible?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: I'm not sure if you think this might be a hacky solution. One easy way to do that could be implement IThisDependency : IDependency and IThatDependency : IDependency to separate the IDependency type. I believe you can also create named instance for the same interface.

Comment: Good Idea, I don't mind it so much but obviously would prefer an out of the box solution if available, I'll fall back to this option if nothing else. Thank you. edit: Maybe this is the 'out of the box solution'

Comment: in fact, I understand that this is a simplified example, but you really want Service and Repository has different IDependency ? I would assume Service contains different components (Repository or whatever) and each of the components has it's dependency. i.e. service dependencies are the component that got injected in constructor. Only component will contains IDependency. The class design will look neater that way and you'll avoid this kinda structureMap setup problem

Comment: I'm looking at the setup and now starting to think that is possible due to poor design that I have this problem, you are correct. I think I can work around this with a better design. IDependacy was actual a UnitOfWork, so the service/repository should share and i think both the services should share the same UnitOfWork too. Coding before thinking about things always end bad. Thanks for your input. Although I won't use any 'answers' provided as I've changed how it works I'd still be interested to know if the above situation is supported.